# ASP.NET - VB.NET - Updating MS_Access table

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to update a record from an Ms-Access table with VB.NET and ASP.NET. I'm getting 2 errors:

- On the web page that's opened I'm getting `Thread was being aborted`
- Web Developer 2010 gives me an error says there's an error in the
  UPDATE statement

This is the code so far:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb


Partial Class ChangePassword
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub btnChange_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnChange.Click

        Dim tUserID As String = Session("UserID")

        Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Brian\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite3\db.mdb;")

        conn.Open()

        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [User] where UserID=?", conn)

        Dim cmd2 = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE USER SET [Password] = '" + txtConfPass.Text + "' where UserID = '" + tUserID + "'", conn)

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", tUserID)

        Dim read As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        Dim read2 As OleDbDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader()


        lblUser.Text = tUserID.ToString
        lblUser.Visible = True

        If read.HasRows Then
            While read.Read()

                If txtOldPass.Text = read.Item("Password").ToString Then

                    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()

                    lblPass.Visible = True


                End If
            End While

        Else
            lblPass.Text = "Invalid Password."
            lblPass.Visible = True

        End If

        conn.Close()

        lblPass.Text = tUserID.ToString
        lblPass.Visible = True
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: Well, there are some problems here.  Your password setting SQL is subject to SQL injection attacks, and this is all very old-school.  Have you considered using SQL Server Express for this?  It's really much better suited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, your cmd2 fails because USER is a reserved word. Enclose in
  square brackets as you already do in the first OleDbCommand.
- Second, to execute a statement like UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE you call
  cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery not ExecuteReader. Don't really needed that call
  after the first for cmd.
- Third, in the first OleDbCommand (cmd) you use a parameter for
  UserID, why in the second one you revert to string concatenation for
  user and password? This opens the door to any kind of Sql Injection
  Attack.
- Fourth, the **Using** statement assure that every Disposable object
  used in your code will be *CLOSED* thus freeing the memory used by
  this commands *ALSO IN CASE OF EXCEPTIONS*.   An example of [Using
  statement here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executenonquery.aspx)

Comment: Steve - Ok I changed those but I think I'm getting an error regarding the session as it is telling me there's no value given for the cmd.

Comment: Also, on the web page when I run the web application it gives me "Thread was being aborted." What does that mean ?

Comment: Can only suggest to check everything about [enabling Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

(1)

```
Dim read2 As OleDbDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader()
```

and then

(2)

```
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Remove (1) - ExecuteNonQuery should do the update.

USER is a keyword in Access, add brackets the same way you have added in the Select statement. Next time, you are faced with a similar problem, print out the statement as Access would see it and try executing it on the database directly - that will point out the errors accurately.

Please use place holders for the update statement similar to the select statement.